# Fancybox full-size on desktop but responsive for mobile?

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, fancybox-2

I currently have the Fancybox plugin installed for a gallery and I have changed the `fitToView` setting to `false` as I want the image to appear full screen on desktop. However when changing the browser window size for mobile, the image doesn't scale anymore?

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For responsiveness effect, you can always combine the API options `fitToView` with `maxWidth` like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        fitToView: false,
        maxWidth: "90%" // or whatever you need
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qLgrchLb/)**